# What is the best practise for java to let call back the class?

Tags: java, methods

Here is the problem:

I got a class called `MyClass`, which is a normal class, have a variable `i`, and `MyOtherClass` will have some logic inside to modify `MyClass`'s i value, but I don't want to pass the `i` value to `MyOtherClass`, I would like them to call `addOne`, and `minusOne` method. How can I modify the `MyOtherClass` to do so? I can modify the constructor of `MyOtherClass` to fulfil this requirement. Thanks.

```
 public class MyClass{

   int i;

   public void myMethod(){

     //I would like to myOtherClass a, b can call back MyClass's addOne, and minusOne
     MyOtherClass a = new MyOtherClass(); 
     MyOtherClass b = new MyOtherClass();

     a.runLogic(); 
     b.runLogin();   
   }

   public void addOne(){
     i++;   
   }

   public void minusOne(){
     i--;   
   }  

   pubic void printI(){
    System.out.print(i);
   }
}
```

The code that use `MyClass`

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); 

myClass.myMethod(); 

myClass.printI();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a reference to `MyClass` into `MyOtherClass`, and call the methods you need directly.

If you're looking for a more generic solution, make `MyClass` implement some interface and accept an instance of that interface in `MyOtherClass` instead. This would allow more flexibility.

```
//here's your interface.
public interface IMyClass{
    void addOne();
    void minusOne();
}

//implement interface in MyClass.
public class MyClass implements IMyClass{/*...*/}

public class MyOtherClass{
    IMyClass myClass;
    public MyOtherClass(IMyClass myClass){
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void test(){
        myClass.addOne();
        myClass.minusOne();
    }
}
```

This is appropriate for more complex types than this.  Here its a bit silly because the class is doing so little, but maybe your example is simplified for something more complicated. Just advice.

Answer (score 5):

Simply pass `this` as argument to the other class constructor or runLogic method:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int i;

    pulic void addOne() {
        i++;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        MyOtherClass c = new MyOtherClass(this);
        c.runLogic();
    }   
}

public class MyOtherClass {
    private MyClass myClass;

    public MyOtherClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void runLogic() {
        myClass.addOne();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass current object of MyClass  to My OtherClass. You can do this by

```
MyOtherClass a = new MyOtherClass(this); 
MyOtherClass b = new MyOtherClass(this);
```

Now inside your MyOtherClass you need to modify your constructor

```
public MyOtherClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }
```

Now you can call any method of myClass  from MyOtherClass

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object of MyClass into the MyOtherClass constructor like

```
Class MyOtherClass 
{
MyClass mc;

// constructor
MyOtherClass (MyClass mc)
{
this.mc = mc;
}

void testMethod(){
  mc.i = 10;        // or whatever you want to assign
}

}
```